# Google OAuth 2.0 sign in error running on localhost

Tags: php, google-oauth

Hello everyone sorry as I am still a newbie at this and I can't get what am I doing wrong or missing.

1: I am getting this error on init and when I click the G+ Sign in button which triggers the popup where I choose the accounts.

> jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/signin.php/activities 404 (Not
>   Found)

What causes this error?

---

2: After the popup, I click the account that I want to login. 
It closes the popup and this error comes out.

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost/signin.php/connect?state={{%20STATE%20}} 404 (Not Found)

Where does this STATE come from or how does it generate?

I found the state in the `index.html`, there is `connectServer: function(code) { ...`

```
url: $(location).attr('origin') + '/signin.php/connect?state={{ STATE }}', ...
```

---

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit: I just cloned the source from git according to this. developers.google.com/+/web/samples/php

3: **Must** my Google Developers Console credential Authorized redirect URIs be set?

Comment: The first error means that somewhere in your script you are trying to do an Ajax Get call using jquery to `http://localhost/signin.php/activities` which doesn't exists.

The second error means that you are trying to do a POST request to that url but the part of {{%20STATE%20}} is not evaluated/rendered. It would be really helpful if you provide us your code so we can find where the error is coming from.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your reply. I just cloned the source from git according to this. https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/php

Edit: Does my Google Developers Console credential Authorized redirect URIs need to be set?

Comment: So I'm following the tutorial to debug the problem. First, you've made a new project in the Google Developers Console and you've enabled the Google+ API, right? Then you've created a new web credential and you've set up your Authorized Javascript Origins to your localhost with the port that you are using for your web server, right? Finally you've copied your client id and secret?

Comment: Then you've cloned the quickstart from github for php and you've moved the folder to where you are serving files, right? In my case I'm using XAMPP as a php server so I've moved the files to myInstallation/htdocs/gplus-quickstart-php. Then you have to open your signin.php file and change the const CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET' and the const CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID' at lines 51 and 46. Then you've executed composer with `composer install` in that folder, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the steps as I described you in the comments and it's working for me. Check the following things:

1. That you execute `composer install` in your project folder to install the dependencies needed for this project. If you are on windows just install composer from `https://getcomposer.com`.
2. Remember to give permission to the entire folder if you are on linux with:

   `chmod +x /var/www/gplus-quickstart-php/signin.php` and
    `chmod -R 555 /var/www/gplus-quickstart-php/vendor`
3. Make sure you change your `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` with YOUR values in the signin.php file.
4. Start the process again if something doesn't work by following the quickstart tutorial on google developers.